# Changing images by clicking links - Javascript

Tags: javascript, image

I have tried to create a simple JavaScript which was supposed to switch images when links are clicked. This is the code of the whole site (It's not much, but it was only meant to be a test):

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Slideshow</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #wrapper {
        width: 800px;
        height: 250px;
        margin: 75px auto auto auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function changeImg(x) {
        document.getElementById(presentationImg).src='x';
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="mainnav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" onClick="changeImg(design.jpg)">Design</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick="changeImg(realisation.jpg)">Realisation</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onClick="changeImg(deployment.jpg)">Deployment</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="presentation">
            <img id="presentationImg" src="design.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>  
</body>
```

I was pretty sure it would work, but it doesn't, and I have no idea why... does anyone know why, and what the solution is?

Comment: Why don't you try a javascript library such as JQuery ?

Comment: @phlogratos - "just use jQuery" is an unhelpful suggestion for someone trying to learn the fundamentals of JavaScript.

Comment: @phlogratos - jQuery isn't always the answer. This is such a simple piece of pure JavaScript, is it really worth including the entire jQuery library just for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the quotes around `x` in your function, and quote the element ID instead:

```
document.getElementById("presentationImg").src = x;
```

You will also need to quote the string you pass in to your function:

```
<a href="#" onclick="changeImg('design.jpg')">
```

The way you have it currently, `presentationImg` will be undefined, as you haven't declared a variable of that name. To make it work the way you had it originally you could do this:

```
var presentationImg = "presentationImg";
document.getElementById(presentationImg).src = x;
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you very much for your lightning-fast answer :)

Comment: @genesis: Yeah I know, but it apparently has a timer, it says I have to wait 1 more minute...

Comment: whoops sorry, did't think about it

Comment: @naveen: Some reference where can I read if this does matter?

Comment: @genesis: i dont see any :) i just assumed so because MDN and W3C defines them like this. is it not the best practice? you confuse me :)

Comment: @naveen & @genesis - It will work fine as `onChange`, but yes, you could say it's best practice to write it all lowercase. I always do (except here, but that's because I copied and pasted from the question!)

Comment: yep. i was just mentioning that. even `OncliCK` will work. i was pointing out it will be better to change as many will refer this in future. :)

Comment: @naveen - Agreed, and changed :)